# I like orange and hate orange

Tags: riddle

[Source:](https://gpuzzles.com/?source=external&stack=1)

> I like orange and at the same time I hate orange, how is this possible?

I rephrased the puzzle from [Gpuzzles](https://gpuzzles.com/?source=external&stack=1) to prevent searching. So don't waste your time.

Comment: When I saw this puzzle, there was no thinking involved. They are just homophones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it sounds like

> You like the fruit but hate the color or vice versa.